# Почему stackoverflow не обновляет подгружаемые библиотеки?

Tags: поддержка

Почему ресурс stackoverflow не обновляет версии подгружаемых библиотек,

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и с какой целью назначили вывод отображения консоли по умолчанию ?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Неужели всем безразлично, или это так сложно реализовать ?

Answer (score -3):

Потому что они не хотят заморачиваться с этим. У каждого свой список любимых библиотек, и они не хотят тратить время на поддержку всего этого зоопарка.

Вы всегда можете подключить любимую библиотеку через кнопку "Добавить внешнюю библиотеку".

Comment: Тогда было правильнее вообще убрать список библиотек

Comment: @andreymal предложите на MSE )